# Too Many New Posts when I Log into my Roleplay Thread

Tags: online-roleplaying, play-by-post

I roleplay online sometimes, but everytime I run into the problem where there's at least 20 pages worth of new posts and it takes me a long time to catch up on a daily basis.

Is there any online or downloadable tool that would facilitate the catch up process?
It could be forum-based or a standalone program in which the roleplaying would happen. Anything that would make it easier to keep up.

Thanks!

Comment: What precisely would you want this tool to do? (If you can't know what's relevant to you without reading those 20 pages of text, I can't see how a tool that's not a true AI could help you go through it any faster.)

Comment: If it's a forum tool, it would be handy if it somehow organized the posts better, or displayed the posts in a more readable fashion (because people's signatures get in the way a lot).

Comment: If it's a stand alone RP app, anything it could do that would make the enormous amounts of posts more managable to read

Comment: Oh, so you're not just looking for help with a specific forum that's causing you this trouble, but also maybe looking for a completely different platform to PbP on?

Comment: No, I believe they're looking for a tool that will make it easier to organise/view a large amount of content in an existing forums RP threads

Answer (score 2):

**Tool to make reading a forum easier**

That would depend on the specific forum software, and would be better asked in uh 'super user' or one of the other stack exchanges relating to internet or computer use.

### Play by Post (Roleplaying in a Forum)

The best forum to roleplay in that I have found is mythweavers.com.  It has a forum software that allows each game to have a miniforum of it's own with multiple threads or categories of threads.

Additionally, too many players and/or GMs in the same thread makes it nigh impossible to have any sort of storytelling, or even like, a conversation in-character.  Same with real life, really.  Multiple threads help with this.  But ultimately organizational issues make 'too large' games slow down and suck in any case.

### Real-Time Geographically Displaced Online Roleplaying (RTGDOR - Roleplaying somewhere else)

roll20.net provides an interactive tabletop for combat, and IRC (Internet Relay Chat) is a traditional medium for online roleplaying with a bot like Bones to provide dice-rolling capability.

Skype video chat is another good online tool for roleplaying.

Ultimately any communication tool can be used for roleplaying, with some limitations based almost solely on dice-rolling.  Which you use is a matter of preference and the specific type of group you have.  Play by Post (forums) is great if people can't get together at a specific time - some form of real-time chat is nearly always superior otherwise.

Comment: I like your answer but my skype experience is pretty bad because of how badly it supports video multi-conversations. I've found Google Hangouts to be better (and has a roll20 app on top of it)